# C#: hiding multiple forms from task manager

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm writing an application which creates a potentially large number of forms to display widgets on the desktop. Every instance of that form shows up in the task manager's Applications list, despite ShowInTaskbar = false; and indeed they do not show in taskbar.

The behavior I want is that only the application's main form shows up in the task manager, how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that the windows also show up in the Alt+Tab bar.  You need to change the window style flags by overriding the CreateParams property.  Here's a full example:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form {
    public Form1() {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
        this.ShowInTaskbar = false;
    }
    protected override CreateParams CreateParams {
        get {
            var cp = base.CreateParams;
            cp.ExStyle |= 0x80;  // Turn on WS_EX_TOOLWINDOW
            return cp;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I've verified that this works.  A perfect solution for hiding a winform window with no border style from the task manager.

Answer (score 0):

You could try setting [FormBorderStyle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hw8kes41.aspx) to one of the tool window options - `FixedToolWindow` or `SizaableToolWindow`. I think that tool windows don't show up in task manager's list of applications, but I'm not positive on that.

Comment: That's neat, it works. However being widget windows, they require FormBorderStyle None, which does show up.

Comment: Edit: the poster below answered while I was trying to figure out the code blocks to post the same answer.